# How to generate POCOs and interfaces from proto files

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, grpc, protobuf-net, grpc-dotnet

My requirement maybe a bit of 'weird' in many people's opinion:

So given a proto file like bellow:

```
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
service Greeter {
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply);
}
```

I want to generate the POCOs and corresponding interfaces (instead of concrete gRPC services) like bellow:

```
public class HelloRequest
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class HelloReply
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
public interface IGreeterService
{
    public HelloReply SayHello(HelloRequest request);
}
```

That is, I only use proto files as some kind of "contract" between different languages (lets say JavaScript and C#), but to skip the "communication" part of the gRPC because we don't need http/2 what's so ever.

I googled a lot but seems there is no such project exists. Now I am thinking of making my own by extending the [grpc-dotnet](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet) project(perhaps with T4 template) , but before start I just need some/any advice/help/information. So here are my questions:

1. Is there are any project/library doing things similar to what I said above which I don't know yet?
2. Does grpc-dotnet have any kind of extendibility that allows me to generate the desired C# types without compiling the proto buffs(Can I get the compiled data structure if there are any)
3. Is it feasible, in terms of dev cost, difficulty etc.
4. Any other advise to put to the right path?

Thank you very much, any comment/answer would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Does this proto3 to C# tool in [Google's compiler](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp-generated) do what you need?

In my experience, T4 templates are fairly difficult to build and debug - but your mileage may vary. In the absence of an existing solution, I would approach this as a simple text parsing problem. If there isn't already a parser for proto files, the easiest solution may be to write a quick console application that would read files from an input directory and generate models and interfaces by manually parsing the text.